# Importing `@vuelidate/core` types not recognized by ESLint

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

The following is recognized by TypeScript

```js
import { Validation, ValidatorFn } from '@vuelidate/core'
```

But gives an error in ESLint:

> ValidatorFn not found in '@vuelidate/core' eslint import/named

How to import types from `@vuelidate/core` ?

Comment: The problem most likely depends on your case, which is unknown. Self-answers are welcome on SO but the question should be suitable for the answer by someone but the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import from `@vuelidate/core/index`:

```js
import { Validation } from '@vuelidate/core/index'
```

This is recognized by both TypeScript and ESLint.

Comment: This solution looks like a hack. . It would be a nightmare if the libs would be unavailable for the regular use without relying on internal structure.